# creating a pivot table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table in sql but am having difficulties.  Here is my problem:  I have a column in my database called 'statusreason', and I need to provide a sum of each statusreason for the past week.  My set is as follows:

[image: StatusReason Count]

I need to pivot this table so that it appears like the following:

[image]

There are a number of statusreasons that are not represented in the above table, since they did not occur in the past week.

The query used to generate the result set is:

```
select inv.statusreason
  , count(inv.statusreason) as 'StatusCount'
from invoicetbl inv (nolock)
inner join trucktbl tru (nolock) on inv.tru_key = tru.tru_key
where inv.client_key = 123
  and inv.createdate > getdate() - 7
group by inv.statusreason
```

If this isn't enough information, please advise what I could add to improve the question.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: What DBMS? SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: SQL Server. Thanks!  If I need to add more please let me know.

Comment: do you know the status reasons ahead of time?  Or will that be determined at run-time?

Comment: The list of possible statusreasons is known and stored in the database, but the ones that will show on this query won't be known until runtime (I hope I understood your question correctly and this adequately answers it).  The list of possible statusreasons are in a table called statusreasontbl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to convert your rows of data into columns, you need to PIVOT the data.  This can be done a number of ways.

If you have a limited number of values that you are going to be returning, then you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select 
    count(case when statusreason = 181 then 1 end) [181],
    count(case when statusreason = 20 then 1 end) [20],
    count(case when statusreason = 212 then 1 end) [212],
    count(case when statusreason = 232 then 1 end) [232]
from
(
    select inv.statusreason
    from invoicetbl inv (nolock)
    inner join trucktbl tru (nolock) 
        on inv.tru_key = tru.tru_key
    where inv.client_key = 123
      and inv.createdate > getdate() - 7
) d;
```

Or you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select [181], [20], [212], [232]
from
(
    select inv.statusreason
    from invoicetbl inv (nolock)
    inner join trucktbl tru (nolock) 
        on inv.tru_key = tru.tru_key
    where inv.client_key = 123
      and inv.createdate > getdate() - 7
) d
pivot
(
    count(statusreason)
    for statusreason in ([181], [20], [212], [232])
) p;
```

If you have an unknown number of values that will be returned, then you will want to look at using dynamic SQL.  This creates a sql string that will then be executed.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(statusreasons ) 
                    from statusreasontbl
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select inv.statusreason
                from invoicetbl inv (nolock)
                inner join trucktbl tru (nolock) 
                    on inv.tru_key = tru.tru_key
                where inv.client_key = 123
                  and inv.createdate > getdate() - 7
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(statusreason)
                for statusreason in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Thank you @bluefeet!  That worked perfectly. The pivot was what I have been trying to do all morning, but your example pointed out what I had incorrect.